# Can you make Netbeans+Xdebug break after a given number of hits?

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

So I have an issue with some PHP code, and I'm not a pro at PHP.
Still, I managed to know where the issue is from, and now I want to see exactly what happens in an iteration, under netbeans.
Then I will have to compare this to a similar result in vs2010 (C# stuff).

My problem is, the issue happens at the 300ish iteration, and in vs2010, I can break only after 300 hits if I want.
Is it possible to do the same thing with Netbeans+Xdebug?

Otherwise it's gonna be a long and boring afternoon of F8 xD

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put an if conditional into your code where you would like to place a breakpoint, like this:

```
if ($someLoopVariable >= 300)
{
  "doNothing"; // make this line a breakpoint
}
```

Did I answer your question, or badly misunderstood it?

Comment: +1. I think this achieves what the question is asking. I don't think there's a more direct way of achieving the desired effect, but this should do the trick.

Comment: I think he's asking if this is implemented in the IDE itself, as in other ones.

Answer (score 0):

As of NetBeans 8.1 there is not a way to do this in the PHP debugger.  However using other languages in NetBeans this feature exists.  To do a conditional breakpoint right click on a break point and select properties to set conditions in other languages; properties is grayed out when debugging PHP.   See the following open case in NetBeans bugzilla report [Bug 132066 - Implement conditional breakpoints](https://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=132066) .  Please vote for this feature if you are interested.  The more votes, we might get this implemented.